# Running a loop of promises in order and waiting for execution to be complete

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm trying to run a loop where a `promise` and its own `then` are created for each iteration. I want to print 'Done' only when all promises are executed (in order). Whatever I do, 'done' is always executed before the 'rendering's!
I know this sounds like a duplicate, but nothing is working, maybe adding a `promise` and a 'then` for each iteration is the problem.

```
        let p = Promise.resolve<void>()
        for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            p = p.then(_ => template.instantiateToElement(data.results[i]).then(res => {
                console.log('rendering');
            }));
        };
        p.then(_ => {
            console.log('done');
        });
```

** template.instantiateToElement() returns a `promise`

Comment: I suppose you should create array of promises (by loop) and then wait as all finish using Promise.all() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Note that `i` when the `template.instantiateToElement(data.results[i])` is executed is the value of `i` after the loop has completed. You need to wrap the promise manipulation inside another function which has `i` as a parameter so the callback function sees the value at the time when the callback was created rather than when it was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that by the time you call `instantiateToElement()` the loop using `i` has completed and the only value for `i` the code will see is `data.results.length`.

You should use a function call to bind the required value of `i`:

```
const instantiate = (i) => (_ => template.instantiateToElement(data.results[i]));
let p = Promise.resolve<void>();
for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    p = p.then(instantiate(i)).then(res => {
        console.log('rendering');
    }));
}
p.then(_ => {
    console.log('done');
});
```

The call to `instantiate(i)` happens during the `for` loop and it creates a function which has `i` bound in a new closure.